# This slider doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with my slider. The thing is that images don't appear after 1 image slide out. It is an old code from YouTube and it says there might be some problems with the `setInterval`, but I checked everything and still nothing. It is the same code as in the video and I can't understand what is the problem.

```js
function Slider(){
 $(".slider #1").show("fade",1500);
 $(".slider #1").delay(5000).hide("slide",{direction:"left"},500);

 var sc = $(".slider img").size();
 var count = 2;
 
 setInterval(function(){
  $(".slider #" + count).show("slide",{direction:"right"},500);
  $(".slider #" + count).delay(5000).hide("slide",{direction:"left"},500);
  if(count == sc){
   count = 1;
  }else{
   count = count + 1;
  }
 },6000);
}
```

```css
.slider {
 overflow:hidden;
 width:800px;
 height:350px;
 margin:30px auto;
}
.slider img{
 width:800px;
 heigth:350px;
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<body onload="Slider();">
 <div class="slider">
  <img id="1" src="img/home/01.jpg" border="0" alt="omage" class="img-responsive">
  <img id="2" src="img/home/02.jpg" border="0" alt="omage" class="img-responsive">
  <img id="3" src="img/home/03.jpg" border="0" alt="omage" class="img-responsive">
  <img od="4" src="img/home/04.jpg" border="0" alt="omage" class="img-responsive">
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what error you are getting?, inspect your webpage and check console

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that the arguments of *.show()* is wrong.
Refer to http://api.jquery.com/show/